# Unable to get remote access to MySQL / MariaDB on Centos7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, iptables

im trying to get remote access to my MySQL / MariaDB server however it keep denying my access. Here is my setup:

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

mysql

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Host <> 'localhost';

+----------+------+
| User     | Host |
+----------+------+
| feed_user| %    |
+----------+------+
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

netstat -plnt

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30227/mysqld
```

The server is within my local network, on a different subnet.

Internal firewall is set to allow connections between the two subnets, can see the traffic being accepted.

Any ideas on why it wont allow me remote access?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Have you tried to connect with the firewall disabled? Just to check and see if it works or not. If it's not working with the firewall disabled then the issue it's not firewall related.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have tried direct access without the Firewall. Thanks, Chris.

Comment: And it works without the firewall or not?!

Comment: Sorry, no it doesnt work with or without.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you telnet on your server's ip address on tcp port 3306 from an external location just to be sure that you can actually connect to mysql?

Comment: No, i could not connect with Telnet. However, im narrowing it down. If i stop the firewalld service on the server, im able to connect with telnet and sql client so obviously there is a problem with the firewall rules on the server itself.

Comment: Ok, so turns out i was adding the rules to iptables instead of firewalld. After adding the rules to firewalld im now able to access it remotely. Just curious, why would a clean install on CentOs install both iptables and firewalld if iptables is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was adding the rules to iptables instead of firewalld. After adding the rules to firewalld i was able to access the the server remotely.